# "Дія над числами" чи "дія з числами"?

Tags: граматика

Добрий день.
Маю питання щодо правильного (з точки зору української мови) вживання деяких математичних термінів. Як правильніше?

1. Дія над числами чи дія з числами? Тобто, дія над чимось чи дія з чимось?
2. Види запису числа чи види запису чисел?

Дякую за допомогу!

Comment: Коли ви робите якісь розрахунки, таким чином виконуєте дію над числами (обчислюєте). Та коли намагаєтесь ділити на нуль, з числами відбуваються цікаві речі.

Answer (score 1):

> <sub>[Дослідження з лексикології і граматики української мови, вип. 12’2012](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:E-B_-jwoRPcJ:www.irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/cgi-bin/irbis_nbuv/cgiirbis_64.exe%3FC21COM%3D2%26I21DBN%3DUJRN%26P21DBN%3DUJRN%26IMAGE_FILE_DOWNLOAD%3D1%26Image_file_name%3DPDF/dlgum_2012_12_6.pdf) > Семантична асиметря опозиції прийменників *над* і *під* в українській мові (О. В. Орленко)</sub>
>
> 4. **Ментальні дії.**
>
> Досить поширеними є абстрактні відношення, які вказують на ментальні дії людини. Цей тип відношень властивий лише прийменнику **над**. Орієнтиром може виступати ментальне поняття, як у (46) або конкретний обʼєкт, як у (47). Ці відношення розвинулися за аналогією до способів опису фізичної роботи (48), заснованих на метонімії: виготовляючи якийсь предмет, людинан ахиляється над ним.
>
> 46. *Тож Ярчик Волшебник, безумовно, мав рацію, коли замислився **над проблемою** головного героя.*
> 47. *Коли вона носила дитину, Корій провів **над нею** певний ритуал.*
> 48. *Деякі з людей зосереджено скніли **над вирізьблюванням** усіляких вигадливо-райських узорів…*

Сюди також підпадають такі приклади:

> <sub>Словник української мови в 20 томах > [Над](//sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=54070&page=1721)</sub>
>
> Обʼєктні відношення
>
> 3. *з оруд. в.* Уживається при позначенні предметів або осіб, з якими пов'язана чи на які спрямована дія.
>
>    - *Він всеньке літо сидів над книжками, писав диктанти* (Григорій Тютюнник);
>    - *Я сидів біля вогнища і розмірковував над ситуацією, в якій опинився* (Д. Білий);
>    - *Робота над черговим шедевром у мого чоловiка просувається як мокре горить* (Г. Вдовиченко);
>
>    Уживається при позначенні осіб, предметів, стосовно яких виявляється яке-небудь ставлення або почуття і т. ін.
>
>    - *Як мати, надо мною осінь плаче, Ласкаво просить: “Сину, не журись!”* (Д. Павличко);
>    - *Вона читає французькі романи, плаче над ними ночами* (В. Кожелянко);

---

Висновка не будить. Бо це просто статтї про *над*, котрі не лише підтверджуїть — для цього наприклад є наприклад корпуси, а пояснюють таке явишче, однак при цьому тут ніяк не заперечуїть приіменник *з* і не відповѣдають шчодо *правильнѣше*. Однак цѣкаво, шчо в такому самому роздѣлѣ — *обʼєктні відношення* — подібного не знайти в статтї про [*з*](//sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=27399&page=918). Спробував в гинших роздѣлах — теж неудало. Можливо я шчо-сь пропустив або не так зрозумѣв, або тут теж яка-сь метонімія. Можливо таки № 19, але приклади менѣ не радують.

Answer (score 0):

1.1) дії як "над", так і "з" числами (однаково часто)

1.2) не зважаючи на "дії над/з числами", тільки в 1/30 випадків "дія" вживається із прийменником "над" (перевірено за допомогою [корпусу](https://mova.institute/bonito/run.cgi/first_form?corpname=zvidusil)). в інших же ~97% вживається "з". тому щоб точно не помилитись, кажіть "дії над"

2) залежить від того чи кажете ви про якесь конкретне число або ж про групу чисел)

Comment: Я не дуже зрозумів «1.2»: Ви кажете, що «дія над» вживається рідше (у 1/30 ≈ 3% випадків), але рекомендуєте вживати саме «дія над»?

Answer (score 0):

Дія завжди "з", "над" є русизмом. Дії **З** числами, знущатися **З** москаля, насміхатися **З** кацапа і т. д.

Спроба пояснити "над" симантикою "безпоседеньої дії" є неправильною, бо ми маємо багато усталених виразів, які легко знайти в словниках фразеологізмів, що очевидно суперечать цій ідеї:

- Роблю чай з лимоном (безпосередньо), а не "роблю чай над лимоном".
- Робити з мух слона (безпосередньо), а не "робити над мухою слона".
- Воювати з вітряками (безпосередньо), а не "воювати над вітряками".
- Викинути з голови (безпосередньо), а не викинути над головою.

Comment: По-моєму, не варто ставити в один ряд «дії з числами» і «знущання з москалів», бо відмінки різні. «Дії з числами» ~ «знущання з москалями», «дії з чисел» ~ «знущання з москалів». (Але «знущання з кимось» зовсім не підходить, бо зазначає радше співучасника, ніж об'єкт; а «дії з чисел» теоретично можна було б розглянути, але ж у питанні не ця форма.)

Comment: @Sasha Я пишу не про відмінок, а лише про те, що для позначення дії з об'єктом застосовується саме прийменник "з", а не над.

Comment: Є таке поняття в мові: "усталений вираз". "Дія з".

Comment: Мені все одно здається, що Ви наводите приклади трішки різних типів, непорівнянні. Але мені важко пояснити свою думку… (Про всяк випадок: мінус Вам ставив і виставляв відповідь на видалення не я. І я в будь-якому разі дуже вдячний Вам за відповідь, хоч і не до кінця з нею згоден.)

Comment: Припускаю: мінус могли поставили за те, що Ви (припустімо) довели усталеність «з», але не довели чужорідність «над». Але це неточно, могли й поставити банально через зовнішній вигляд (люблять тут довгі відповіді з посиланнями).

Comment: А свою думку я все-таки спробую пояснити [тут](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143028/), хоч це не так важливо.

Comment: Вибачте, мені не прийшли сповіщення про Ваші повідемлення у чаті, тому я відповів на них тільки зараз :(.

Answer (score 0):

> І се, безперечно, не було виїмкове явище: Руська Правда, як ми бачили, припускає, що можуть бути такі люди, що входять у грошеві **операції з холопом**, навіть і знаючи,що він холоп… (Михайло Грушевський, «Історія України-Руси. Том III», 1900).
>
> Скінчивши цю **операцію з ножицями**, Старковський вживає останнього способу «благородних героїв» бити по серцях глядачів: божеволіє (Леонід Чулий, «Біографія», 1910).

> Звичайно бувало, що ті ґудзики за кілька день знов десь пропадали й знов Вітрові доводилось вислухувати товариські картання й терпеливо переносити нові **операції над своїм пальто** (Сергій Єфремов, «Пам'яті Василя Доманицького», 1910).
>
> Всі **операції над собою** він терпів стойко, ні разу не зрадивши свою славу «мовчунчика» (Володимир Винниченко, «Божки», 1914).

*Дія/операція з чимось* і *дія/операція над чимось* мають трішки різну семантику. ***Над чимось* зазначає саме безпосередній об'єкт дії/операції, а *з чимось* — щось (когось), що бере участь у дії/операції, але необов'язково є прямим об'єктом**. Тобто *над чимось* вужче за *з чимось*; у вищенаведених прикладах можна замінити *над* на *з* («операції зі своїм пальто[м]», «операції з собою»), але не навпаки («операції над холопом», «операцію над ножицями» — це вже змінить зміст фраз).

До чисел загалом підходять обидві семантики (числа умовно можна вважати і «скалпелем», і «пацієнтом»), тож я поки не бачу причин надавати перевагу якій одній із цих форм. Можливо, [Vitalii у своїй відповіді](/a/7164) має рацію, що форма *з чимось* з'явилася раніше й загалом притаманніша українській мові, та не мені про це судити.

Comment: Як на мене, Грушевський і тим більше Руська правда є трохи застарими джерелами для відповіді на запитання про стан справ в сьогоднішній мові.

Руська правда взагалі написана мовою, яку важко назвати українською, а Грушевський мав свій власний і досить екзотичний правопис. Те ж саме стосується і Винниченка.

Для пояснення сьогоднішнього правила підійшов би сьогоднішній підручник, правопис чи тлумачний словник, а не приклади з тексту сторічної чи вісімсотрічної давнини з текстів, грамотність яких ще треба довести, бо вони не є підручниками, а лише пам'ятками літератури.

Comment: За такою логікою виходить, що я "готую чай НАД лимоном", а не "З лимоном", адже тут я дію на лимон безпосередньо ножем та ложкою?

Comment: Ще один всім відомий усталений вираз: "Вийти сухим із води". Я тут безпосередньо чи опосередковано з води виходжу? Може, треба "Вийти сухим НАД води"?
Або "воювати з вітряками" - Дон Кіхот цілком безпосередньо вдарив вітряк списом, тож він воював НАД вітряками? Ще: "Робити з мухи слона" - безпосередньо, беремо муху, додаємо хобот, отримуємо слона - тож "Робити НАД мухою слона", чи як?

Comment: По-моєму, це не зовсім релевантні приклади. Див. докладніше в [тому ж чаті](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143028/).